# What would the value of $\int_0^{\infty} \tan(x) \,dx$ be?

Tags: definite-integrals

We cannot take the definite integral of $\tan(x)$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$, just like we can't take the definite integral of $1/x$ on  $]0, 1]$; but what would happen if we took the definite integral of $\tan(x)$ between $[0, \infty[$  ? Would it converge and lead to a result ? just like: $$\int_0^{\infty}  e^{-2x} \,dx$$

Comment: Is $tg(x)$ the tangent function?

Comment: yes; that's the way we write it in Hungary.

Comment: What would happen is that one would get an "even more" undefined quantity.

Comment: Yeah this isn't Riemann integrable over the interval. Infinities don't cancel, though it's tempting.

Comment: hmm... interesting; according to my plotting program, the area is around -1.043E+7

Comment: @Mattmatt Plotting programs do not handle "cancelling" infinities very well, i.e. they sometimes believe that they actually cancel (since their methods are unable to see any problem with the integration in the first place). I guess it would say that $\int_{-1}^1\frac1xdx$ is well-defined as well.

Comment: @Arthur nope; for 1/x over ]0, 1], it says **undefined**

Comment: it's actually really reliable

Comment: @MattMatt "aroud" minus ten millions... The point is that, depending on the subdivisions of $[0,\infty[\,\setminus \left\{\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\,:\,k\in\Bbb N\right\}$ your algorithm considers, you'll get completely different results (that's somehow what "not Riemann integrable" means).

Comment: that makes more sense, yes

Comment: @MattMatt Arthur mentioned the integral of $1/x$ on $(-1,1)$, not on $(0,1)$ hence the "undefined" you got for the latter is offtopic for the former.

Comment: That integral move between ∞ and 0.

Comment: It is equal to $\ln 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the definite integral on $]0,\infty[$ to be well-defined, the integrand must approach 0 as x approaches $\infty$. Clearly, tan(x) doesn't do that, so we can't talk about $\int_0^\infty tan(x)dx$. 
What about $\int_0^{\pi/2} \tan(x)dx$?
Well since the indefinite integral of $tan(x)$ is $\ln[\sec(x)]$, we see that $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}[\ln \sec(x)] = \ln \infty = \infty$ is unbounded, and thus the area of even one period of tangent does not converge.